# !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

first = ("original_02.png")
second = ("modified_02.png")


imageA = cv2.imread("first")
imageB = cv2.imread("second")


grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))


thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)


for c in cnts:

    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(imageA, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(imageB, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)


cv2.imshow("Original", imageA)
cv2.imshow("Modified", imageB)
cv2.imshow("Diff", diff)
cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is my code and I'm getting the error witch I have mentioned in the title.
and I have kept code and necessary files in the same folder

grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-j8nxabm_\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

above is the error I'm getting

Comment: You're not actually loading your image files. Try `cv2.imread(first)` without the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that your images are empty.

Why is that? — Because your code is trying to read (nonexistent) files with names `'first'` and `'second'`. In reality you want to read the *variables* of those names.

Hence remove the quotation marks. Furthermore, there’s no reason to put your variable names in parentheses — remove these, too. At the moment it looks like you intend to define these variables as *tuples* (but you’re not):

```
first = "original_02.png"
second = "modified_02.png"

imageA = cv2.imread(first)
imageB = cv2.imread(second)
```

Next, you should check whether this actually worked. [The documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) notes that

> If the image cannot be read (…), the function returns an empty matrix

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading the image but a string into imread. `imread()` interprets this as a path and probably returns `None` because it doesn't find the path.
Instead try:

```
first = ("original_02.png")
second = ("modified_02.png")


imageA = cv2.imread(first)
imageB = cv2.imread(second)
```